# Change Description character limit and make it required Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am quite a Beginner at SharePoint online can you please let me know
if there is an option to change the Description character limit on a modern site at the page settings?
I was looking everywhere and I could not find it

Answer (score 0):

You can **assign a display limit** to the *Description* column by changing the value under “**Number of lines for editing**” via *List settings* > Description column > *Edit Column*.

Or you can remove the line limit by set “**Allow unlimited length in document libraries**” to **Yes**. Note that this option is only available in document libraries.

*Description* column (or other Multiple lines of text columns) has a limit of **63,999** characters by default, which cannot be increased.

[image]

Reference: [List and library column types and options.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7) (Check out Section “**Multiple lines of text**”.)

---

**UPDATE:**
The **[Page Description](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-edit-and-add-page-details-778018d3-8269-4fd2-a55d-8c0e5b72b938)** field under **Page details** is not the same field as *Description* column in the Page library, and the 255-character limit cannot be modified or removed from our end.

[image]

You can submit this idea via the UserVoice forum if you are in great need of this feature: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration

Comment: Hi Chealsea_MSFT and thanks a lot for your answer,  maybe my question was not clear enough I am trying to change the Description char length at the Page Details in the  site pages I am trying to edited from site contents -> site pages -> Description -> column settings -> More Options -> Allow unlimited length in document libraries change the toggle to yes click save and then the description keeps staying off, Again I am trying to change the Page details description field , this will drive me nuts, thanks in advance again

Comment: @Nauagio Sorry for misunderstanding. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Chelsea_MSFT Sorry for the late reply, **thanks a lot for your answer**

Comment: @Nauagio No problem. If you decide to open a UserVoice post, you can post the link back here so other users with similar request would vote for it. Also, would you please give it a vote or accept it as answer if you find the reply helpful? It will help others in this forum to find answers quickly as well.